# Send Data to a Django UpdateAPIView through Axios

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios

I am sending `Email` in the body of an `Axios patch request`.

```
const userData = await this.$axios.patch(`/user/${id}/update/`, {
          email: value
        })
```

I am sending it to this API View in with Django rest framework

```
class UserAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.UserDetailsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return User.objects.filter(id='id')
```

I tried running it on Swagger and Postman and it is working good, but in Axios, it throws an error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Is there any other way of sending it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In js code, your email value is undefined, please try to hardcode some value for email and check if it works?

```
const userData = await this.$axios.patch(`/user/${id}/update/`, {
          email: "hardcode@email.com" 
        })
```

if it works, then you should check your js code why it is not setting the value of email.